# use .htaccess file to redirect request

Tags: .htaccess, web, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Im currently struggling to get my .htaccess file to work how i want it.

When a request is sent to `https://spitfox.com/riot/get` it should use port 49876
When another request is sent to `https://spitfox.com/browser/get` it should use port 3336

Im currently expirimenting with this file:

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^riot$ http://127.0.0.1:49876/ [P,N]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:49876/$1 [P,N]
RewriteRule ^browser http://127.0.0.1:3336/ [P,N]


Options All -Indexes
```

and it works for the /riot/get part but not for the /browser/get part and i cant figure out why.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it with trial and error!

This is the solution:

```
   RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^riot$ http://127.0.0.1:49876/ [P,N]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^browser/get$ http://127.0.0.1:3336/browser/get [P]
RewriteRule ^browser/add$ http://127.0.0.1:3336/browser/add [P,QSA]
RewriteRule ^browser/update$ http://127.0.0.1:3336/browser/update [P,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:49876/$1 [P,L]


Options All -Indexes
```